# Why are the vector potential components assumed zero when the respective current density components are?

Tags: electromagnetism, coordinate-systems, vector-fields

My texbooks assumes that for example if $j_x=0$, then $A_x=0$, as a starting point to find the vector potential of a circuit with current density $\vec{j}$, but from the equation $\nabla^2 \vec{A} =-\mu_0\vec{j}$, which for the x component is: $\nabla^2 A_x =-\mu_0\ j_x=0$, the solution is not necessarily zero, as instance $A_x=c_1x+c_2y+c_3z+c_4$ is a possible solution among many others

For example in the case of an infinite line of current along the z axis, $j_x=0$ and $j_y =0$ and the texbook assumes directy that $A_x=0$ and $A_y=0$ (the symmetry argument is not convincing or detailed enough)

How can I prove mathematically that the solution is $0$?

Comment: NO, It's the laplacian applied to every component of the vector

Comment: that's a notation used by some authors, there is nothing wrong with it

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver Then use minus $\nabla^2 \vec {A}=-\mu_0\vec {j}$, and also don't forget  that in this case $\nabla .\vec {A}=0$

Comment: yes, I forgot the minus, I corrected that

Answer (score 1):

If you use the equation $\nabla^2 {\bf A} = -\mu_0 {\bf J}$, then you have made the choice that $\nabla \cdot {\bf A} = 0$.

However ${\bf A}$ is not unique. You may add the gradient of *any* scalar function to ${\bf A}$ and it will not affect the magnetic field inferred from it. i.e.
$$\nabla \times ({\bf A} + \nabla \psi) = \nabla \times {\bf A}$$

Similarly, as long as the scalar function also satisies $\nabla^2 \psi =0$ then $\nabla \cdot {\bf A}$ is still zero. i.e.
$$ \nabla \cdot ({\bf A} +\nabla \psi) = 0\ \ \ {\rm if}$$
$$ \nabla \cdot \nabla \psi = \nabla^2 \psi = 0$$

So I think the answer is yes, you can add those terms to your solution and providing they can be produced from the gradient of a scalar function $\psi$ and providing they satisfy $\nabla^2 \psi =0$, then the B-field is unchanged.